# How to save the context of an api and use it to create an order history

Tags: python, jquery, django, api, rest

I am using the transbank api to simulate the purchase of a product through an app of a bank, and I need to save the data generated at the end of the purchase to show them in a purchase history of the user, and I do not know how to do that, thanks in advance.

Here is the code of: successful payment

```
    @csrf_exempt
    def pago_exitoso(request, id):
    
        if request.method == "GET":
            token = request.GET.get("token_ws")
            print("commit for token_ws: {}".format(token))
            commercecode = "597055555532"
            apikey = "579B532A7440BB0C9079DED94D31EA1615BACEB56610332264630D42D0A36B1C"
            tx = Transaction(options=WebpayOptions(commerce_code=commercecode, api_key=apikey, 
            integration_type="TEST"))
            response = tx.commit(token=token)
            print("response: {}".format(response))
    
            user = User.objects.get(username=response['session_id'])
            perfil = PerfilUsuario.objects.get(user=user)
            form = PerfilUsuarioForm()
            producto = Producto.objects.get(id=id)
    
            context = {
                "buy_order": response['buy_order'],
                "session_id": response['session_id'],
                "amount": response['amount'],
                "response": response,
                "token_ws": token,
                "first_name": user.first_name,
                "last_name": user.last_name,
                "email": user.email,
                "rut": perfil.rut,
                "direccion": perfil.direccion,
                "response_code": response['response_code'],
                "producto": producto
                
            }
            return render(request, "core/pago_exitoso.html", context)
        else:
            return redirect(index)
```

---- And here is the code : Start payment

```
    @csrf_exempt
    def iniciar_pago(request, id):
        print("Webpay Plus Transaction.create")
        buy_order = str(random.randrange(1000000, 99999999))
        session_id = request.user.username
        amount = Producto.objects.get(id=id).precio
        return_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/pago_exitoso/'+ id
    
        # response = Transaction.create(buy_order, session_id, amount, return_url)
        commercecode = "597055555532"
        apikey = "579B532A7440BB0C9079DED94D31EA1615BACEB56610332264630D42D0A36B1C"
    
        tx = Transaction(options=WebpayOptions(commerce_code=commercecode, api_key=apikey, integration_type="TEST"))
        response = tx.create(buy_order, session_id, amount, return_url )
        print(response['token'])
    
        perfil = PerfilUsuario.objects.get(user=request.user)
        form = PerfilUsuarioForm()
    
        context = {
            "buy_order": buy_order,
            "session_id": session_id,
            "amount": amount,
            "return_url": return_url,
            "response": response,
            "token_ws": response['token'],
            "url_tbk": response['url'],
            "first_name": request.user.first_name,
            "last_name": request.user.last_name,
            "email": request.user.email,
            "rut": perfil.rut,
            "direccion": perfil.direccion,
            
        }
    
        return render(request, "core/iniciar_pago.html", context)
```

Comment: Why don't you create a model where you would save these data?

Comment: I did it, but I don't know how to save the context generated by the api and save it in a model.